# Connect MongoDB to ElasticSearch by MongoConnector in Kubernetes

Tags: cluster, mongodb, kubernetes, elasticsearch

I have a MongoDB and ElasticSearch cluster which I've run by Kubernetes.

I am trying to connect my ElasticSearch to MongoDB on Kubernetes but I can't find any relevant document.

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Did you try it on Docker Swarm?

Comment: no i just want try this on 'Kubernetes'

Answer (score 0):

You can look at Mongo-connector, it is a sync service that creates the pipeline from a `Mongodb` cluster to one or more target systems, i.e. `ElasticSearch`. More relevant information you can get from official GitHub [project](https://github.com/yougov/mongo-connector#doc-managers) or [Wiki](https://github.com/yougov/mongo-connector/wiki) page.

Comment: As mentioned in Installation section, the Mongo Connector 2.5.0 support Elasticsearch 5.x. https://github.com/yougov/mongo-connector/wiki/Usage-with-ElasticSearch#installation
I need to know, can i use it for Elasticsearch 7.2?